# If-else Statement or command inside a function?

Tags: bash

It's possible to have an if-else inside a function?

Here I have the menu.

Please see codes below.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Main Menu

function p_enter
{
    echo ""
    echo -n "Press Enter to continue"
    read
    clear
}

function df1
{
read var
if [ $var = "1" ]
 then
 echo "nice"
 else
 echo "not bad"
 fi
   }



    select=
    until [ "$select" = "0" ]; do
        echo ""
        echo "MAIN MENU"
        echo "1 - XML DATA REPORT"
        echo "2 - SOON "
        echo ""
        echo "0 - exit"
        echo ""
        echo -n "Enter sleection: "
        read select
        echo ""

    case $select in
            1 ) df1 ; press_enter ;;
            2 ) free ; press_enter ;;
            3 ) exit ;;
            * ) echo "nvalid entry"; press_enter
     esac
     done
```

Any tips or suggestions?

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: Yes? Is there a specific issue you have with this?

Comment: Yes, I really asking if how can I insert and different commands in function especially if-else statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a shell function can use if/else statements.

```
#!/bin/bash

function comment_on_val {
    local the_reply="$1"
    local the_word="$2"

    if (( the_reply == 1 )); then
        echo "The value is one ($the_word)"
    else
        echo "The value isn't one ($the_word)"
    fi
}

echo "Menu:"
select word in "Yes" "No" "Exit"; do
    case "$REPLY" in
        3) break    ;;
        *) comment_on_val "$REPLY" "$word"   ;;
    esac
done
```

The only reason I use `local` in the function is to give the two variables local scope.  If I didn't, they would exist in the main body of the script after calling `comment_on_val`, which in this case is not intended.

Comment: so local is required on the function side?

Comment: @JJ-SAMA No, it's just a declaration to make them have scope within the function body. It's not required.

Comment: @JJ-SAMA I added a note about this to my answer.

Comment: Why did you put quotes around `$1` and `$2`?

Comment: @felwithe Quotes are not usually needed in simple assignments like `a=$1`, and in `bash` it's not strictly needed with `export a=$1` and `declare a=$1`, but other shells need the quotes for `export a="$1"`.  If in any form of doubt, always double quote all expansions.  See e.g. [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)