# Bash function with if then returns command not found

Tags: bash, bash-functions

I'm trying to write a function that does this:

```
$ test-function -u {local-path} {destination}
```

If the first parameter is `-u`, then execute a function that takes the next 2 parameters as the path of the file to upload/copy/rsync and the destination.

```
$ test-function -d {local-path} {destination}
```

If the first parameter is not `-u` (or it is `-d`), then execute a function that takes the next 2 parameters as the path of the file to download/copy/rsync (given that I'm at the current folder) and the destination.

I've found answers that suggest the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668170/if-statement-and-calling-function-in-if-using-bash) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297574/if-else-statement-or-command-inside-a-function). However, my function in my `.bash_profile` returns errors like this:

```
function test_func {
    local a="$1"
    local a="$2"

    if ( a == "-u" ); then
        echo "This means upload"
    else
        echo "This means download"
    fi
}

alias test-function="test_func"
```

Then:

```
$ test-function -u
-bash: a: command not found
This means download
$ test-function -d
-bash: a: command not found
This means download
```

If I change the code to:

```
if [[a == "-u"]]; then
...
```

This happens:

```
$ test-function -u
-bash: [[a: command not found
This means download
```

If I change the code according to one of the answers I found:

```
if ((a == "-u")); then
...
```

This happens:

```
line 53: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

I guess this error is related to the double `((...))`.
How do you do it?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is here:

```
if ( a == "-u" ); then
    echo "This means upload"
else
    echo "This means download"
fi
```

The `if` construct expects an expression that can be evaluated to true or false. So, for example, a command (`if ls; then echo yes;fi`) or a test construct. You want to use a test construct but you're not using the test operator (`[`), you are using parentheses.

The parentheses just open a subshell. Therefore, the expression `( a == "-u" )` just means "run the command `a` with the arguments `==` and `"-u"` in a subshell. What you want is:

```
if [ "$a" = "-u" ]; then  ## you also need the $ here
    echo "This means upload"
else
    echo "This means download"
fi
```

Or, if you want to use the non-portable `[[ ]]` construct which works in `bash`, you need a space after the `[[`:

```
if [[ "$a" == "-u" ]]; then
    echo "This means upload"
else
    echo "This means download"
fi
```

You tried `if [[a == "-u" ]]` so the shell read `[[a` as a single command and failed.

Finally, the `(( ))` construct which, again is not portable, but does work in bash (and some other shells) is used for arithmetic evaluations. From `man bash`:

```
  ((expression))
          The  expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under
          ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is  non-zero,  the
          return  status  is  0; otherwise the return status is 1.  This is exactly
          equivalent to let "expression".
```

So this isn't something you would want to use in this context.Putting all this together, you want something like this:

```
function test_func {
    local a="$1"

    if [ "$a" = "-u" ]; then
        echo "This means upload"
    else
        echo "This means download"
    fi
}

alias test-function="test_func"
```

Comment: Note that the standard `[` syntax is `[ a = -u ]` (or `[ "$a" = -u ]` if the intention was to check the value of the `a` variable which would make more sense). The `[` builtin of `bash` and a few other shells do support both `=` and `==` though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use official syntax and use `[` .... `]` for the `test` calls.

- `( ... )` creates a sub-shell
- `(( ))` is a ksh specific internal arithmetic expression that likes numbers instead of `-u`

Comment: `((...))` is also supported (with variations) by `bash` and `zsh` and have been for decades so it's no longer ksh-specific. Note `-u` is fine, that's like `(-1 * ${u:-0})`, those `"` characters are a problem though.

Comment: Well, it has been introduced in ksh88 and at that time there have been neither `bash` nor `zsh`;-)

Comment: `((...))` is indeed originally a ksh extension (long before ksh88 btw), but is no longer ksh-specific, which is the point I was making.

Comment: Well I mention it because some people usually call things like that a `bashism`.